# How to plot marginal distribution of each attribute?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, kernel-density, density-plot

I am trying to plot the marginal distributions of each attribute `c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")` for each of the three `"Species"` of `iris`. Essentially, for each `"Species"` I need 4 marginal distribution plots. I tried to use the `ks` package but cannot seem to split them up into separate species.

I used the following:

```
attach(iris)
library(ks)
library(rgl)
library(misc3d )
s <- levels(iris$Species)
fhat <- kde(x=iris[iris$Species == s[1], 2])
plot(fhat, cont=50, xlab="Sepal length", main="Setosa")
```

Is there a way to put this in a loop to produce the 12 plots required? How do I plot it for 2 dimensions?

Comment: Apologies, have updated question accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Using `ggplot` you can arrange all densities in one plot. To do so you need to first pivot the data into long format and can then `facet` by the variables and Species:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  pivot_longer(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ name + Species, scales = "free")
```

[image]